# Restoring from backup made with rsync -M--fake-super

Tags: backup, rsync, symbolic-link, restore, ownership

For years I have been regularly running the following command locally as a root filesystem backup in the hope I am safe:

```
rsync -aAXv --progress --delete / --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} -M--fake-super me@server:~/backup
```

Now that I actually need to restore it skeletons seem to fall out of the cupboard:

I found that symlinks became regular files on the remote end, containing the link as their content. I expected that the option `-a` implied `-l` to save symlinks as symlinks. Was it the `fake-super` that made the difference?

How can one restore from a backup made like that? I am currently running this as root, but owner becomes root everywhere so something must be wrong:

```
rsync -aAXv --progress --delete --fake-super -M--super me@server:~/backup /mount/point
```

Unfortunately the rsync manual is not straightforward to me with the `fake-super` related options. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

When restoring, `--fake-super` needs to be used on the "reader" side (so that it would decode the xattrs back into "real" metadata). As you're restoring from a remote server to local filesystem, the option needs to be passed on to that server using `-M`, *not* used locally.

Comment: This was how I started out, so I assumed that coding/decoding depends on if it the remote is source or destination. But when used ```-M--fake-super``` also when restoring, the owner of all the files became the owner of the files on the remote end.

Comment: @kralg that sounds like you weren't running restore as root, so ownerships couldn't be restored

Comment: I did run it as root and every file became owned by root. Would be nice to see a working example.